# How can I query against a boolean when using LINQ in CosmosDB SDK v3.0 sync count queries?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, azure-cosmosdb

I am using a synchronous pattern to count items held in CosmosDB, specifying a predicate and using GetItemLinqQueryable

This works nicely, counting all `ReportRecord` items with a specific field value:

```
 var count = _cosmosClient.GetContainer(DATABASE_ID, CONTAINER_ID)
                .GetItemLinqQueryable<ReportRecord>(true)
                .Count(r => r.Name.Equals("Smith"));
```

However, if I try to check a boolean is true in the predicate it doesn't seem to work, i.e. all records are counted but I only want those where `Answer` is true. Maybe its a syntax issue in my Linq, or my fundamental understanding is wrong.

```
 var count = _cosmosClient.GetContainer(DATABASE_ID, CONTAINER_ID)
                .GetItemLinqQueryable<ReportRecord>(true)
                .Count(r => r.Answer);
```

or

```
 var count = _cosmosClient.GetContainer(DATABASE_ID, CONTAINER_ID)
                .GetItemLinqQueryable<ReportRecord>(true)
                .Count(r => r.Answer == true);
```

For reference, the ReportRecord looks like this:

```
public class ReportRecord
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Answer { get; set; }
    }
```

If I switch to the asyn pattern below, then I can query successfully using the following, but I really want to use the sync pattern here for consistency.

```
List<ReportRecord> results = new List<ReportRecord>();
var container = _cosmosClient.GetContainer(DATABASE_ID, CONTAINER_ID);
var query = new QueryDefinition("SELECT * FROM Reports p WHERE p.answer = true");

using (FeedIterator<ReportRecord> resultSetIterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<ReportRecord>(query))
{
     while (resultSetIterator.HasMoreResults)
     {
        FeedResponse<ReportRecord> response = await resultSetIterator.ReadNextAsync();
        results.AddRange(response);
     }
}

return results.Count;
```

Comment: I am able to run your code without any issues. It gave me the correct count.

Comment: Have the underlying values been stored as string instead of bool?

Comment: In my experience it's better to avoid LINQ and use `QueryDefinition` instead, exactly for this reason that things might not work as you expect. Also, this kind of operation is the reason `async` was created.

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav Mantri, thats really interesting. I guess I must be doing something wrong. Please can you confirm that you used the same model ReportRecord, same LINQ expression and were connecting to a SQL API cosmos container?

Comment: @DavidG, unless I am missing something, the fact that Answer is defined as a bool must mean its stored as a bool in the database right?
`public bool Answer { get; set; }`

Comment: Not necessarily, I have no idea how the data arrived in your database. Are you able to display the raw content of the store? It should give you the raw JSON I think.

Comment: `Please can you confirm that you used the same model ReportRecord, same LINQ expression and were connecting to a SQL API cosmos container?` - I did not use the same model and modify the LINQ query based on my model.

Comment: I just tried it by creating some sample data using the model you're using and it still worked ok for me.